# Remove accent for specific strings R

Tags: r

I would like to remove the accent "é" in a large dataset, but only for the strings in the list.

Here below a small replicable example:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringi)

data <- data.frame (territory  = c("Abbécourt", "Achéres", "Beaumé", "Belvezé", 
"Marré"))

# I create a list of string for which I want to remove the accent
strings<-c("Abbécourt","Achéres","Belvezé")
strings <- paste(paste0("^", strings[order(-nchar(strings))], "$"), collapse = "|")
```

What I do is:

```r
data <- data %>% dplyr::mutate(territory = gsub("é", "e", territory))
```

but of course the command removes all the "é" in the dataset.

I can't find a way to have the following output:

```r
territory
1 Abbecourt
2   Acheres
3    Beaumé
4   Belveze
5     Marré
```

Thank you very much for your help,
Best Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a condition with `case_when/ifelse` to check for the presence of the elements `%in%` the strings and then only modify those elements with `gsub/str_replace_all`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   mutate(territory = case_when(territory %in% strings ~ 
    str_replace_all(territory, "é", "e"), TRUE ~ territory))
```

-output

```
  territory
1 Abbecourt
2   Acheres
3    Beaumé
4   Belveze
5     Marré
```